# Fixed/variable length structure in c# and big endian conversion

Tags: c#, c++, structure, endianness

```
Struct {
 byte F1[2]
 SHORT F2
 byte F3[512]
} BPD


CBD
{
 SHORT CLENGTH
 byte DATA[]
}
```

Above are 2 c++ structure. Here SHORT is of 2 byte signed.
What would be the best way to convert it into C#?

(Note that in 2nd struture length of DATA is uundefined.)

I have seen following two links.

[Fixed length strings or structures in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415214/fixed-length-strings-or-structures-in-c)

and

[Reading a C/C++ data structure in C# from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-from-a-byte-array)

After reading data into structure i need to covert the short variable to big endian. (reversing bytes).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved myself.

Structures are good but if you are not going to modify any data classes are better to use.
I have create classes in c# for c++ structure and for big to little endian conversion i have create 3 library functions and it works for me.

Thnaks everybody for the valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

Only 'short' is needed to be converted. Array of bytes identical on big/little endian platform.

So, just read structures and do something like this:

data.F2 = ((uint)data.F2 >> 8) | ( ((uint)data.F2 & 0xFF) << 8);

and

data.CLENGTH = ((uint)data.CLENGTH >> 8) | ( ((uint)data.CLENGTH & 0xFF) << 8);

Comment: Thanks for the response. My first questiion is stll there. 
The best way to extract data from a byte array. 
Converting it into structure? 
Putting byte data into a class constructor and processing it into class?

I have more than 100 structure to handle and these are nested upto 10 level.

Comment: For the first structure - yes, 'C# value type' is an optimal.

For second structure, it's better to replace it to one dynamic array.

Comment: I need to covert not only short but LONG,DOUBLE etc.. also
As per my specs

If your system uses little-endian order, the data types which occupy more than one byte should be twiddled (byte reversed).

Comment: Yes, every basic type except 'char', 'byte' and 'array of chars' must be converted.